# Laravel sending mail issue after site migration

Tags: php, laravel

I know this question has been asked many times before, but I have attempted a lots of these solutions without any success.

Hello i have issue in sending mail to laravel as its working fine but after migrating site to other server with ssl and now having issue as its giving below error.

`Expected response code 220 but got code \"\", with message \"\"`

below is the code used for `.end` and `mail.php`

`.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

`mail.php`

```
<?php

return [

     'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER'),
     'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),
     'port' => env('MAIL_PORT'),
     'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'developer.eww@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'GBAN'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION','tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/lib/sendmail -i -t',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: That your other site has SSL has no bearing on your email sending. If you've switched hosting providers, it's probably that the new provider is blocking outbound SMTP, which is very common. You'll need to read their docs, ask their support.

Comment: I found that using my API in postman its works couple of times but suddenly stopped working so i can say that hosting providers support smtp

Comment: I assume there is some debug option in Laravel mail to show the SMTP conversation - I suggest you enable that. One likely issue is that you might be trying to do SMTP+STARTSSL (explicit TLS) when it's expecting SMTPS (implicit TLS), so perhaps try using port 587.

Comment: I resolved it by this command `php artisan config:cache`